# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, type-conversion

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass
```

this seems to be inconsistent with other "to_"

eg with Rails 3.2.14, and ruby 1.9.3p362:

```
1.9.3p362 :055 > nil.to_f
 => 0.0 
1.9.3p362 :056 > nil.to_d
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for nil:NilClass
1.9.3p362 :057 > nil.to_s
 => "" 
1.9.3p362 :058 > nil.to_i
 => 0
```

it means that when ever i might want to convert to big decimal that i first have to make sure the value is not nil and assign it a 0 value anyway... so... comments on what is the best way to make this consistent? and should i consider this a bug?

Comment: Also, `nil.to_a` => [], but `nil.to_sym` => undefined method (natch). Can't answer your question, however.

Answer (score 6):

`to_d` isn't part of core Ruby. It's part of the BigDecimal package; specifically you get it when you `require "bigdecimal/util"`. It monkey-patches itself into some of the core classes, but as you've discovered, not all of them.

If you just want `nil.to_d` to return `nil` (which seems like the only sensible thing for it to return), you can monkey-patch it yourself:

```
class NilClass
  def to_d
    nil
  end
end

irb(main):015:0> nil.to_d
=> nil
```

If you want it to return an actual BigDecimal with value 0, then return `BigDecimal.new(0)` instead, but I think `nil` should be `nil`.

Comment: yes, i did know that it was part of a different package.

i agree with you, that what it should be doing not complaining and returning nil. the other to_ are instead manufacturing data, turning what meaningfully was stating "nothing here" to a value of 0.

however, i would tend to want consistency over exception and thus would probably want it to do the same thing that the others are doing.

this behavior seems almost deliberate consider the following:

1.9.3p362 :001 > 1+nil+2
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
1.9.3p362 :002 > 1+nil.to_f+2
 => 3.0

Answer (score 2):

or 
`(nil.try(:to_d) || 0) + value`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `#try`, which will return `nil` if the receiver is `nil`, or call the method if the receiver is not nil

```
nil.try :to_d
#=> nil

1.try :to_d
#=> #<BigDecimal:7ffe8e39c1e8,'0.1E1',9(36)>
```

Comment: the problem i see with this is that your code would become excessively littered with trys. in my my way of thinking, i would rather deal with potential exceptions vs being heavy handed about preventing them. i.e.: code that always has to happen vs only happening when needed.

Comment: @boar: Ultimately, it's a case of guarding against your input. I would try to take another code path if you have a nil value, rather than monkey patch or try my way out of it

Answer (score 0):

you're probably better off converting to a string first if that's what you need

```
BigDecimal.new(amount.to_s)
```